# WSL2 GUI App (Ubuntu 22.04 welcome screen) is cut in diagonal

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, wsl2

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from the Microsoft Store, and this happened, already tried twice, but still the same problem

[image]

UPDATE:
My GPU is Asus TUF nVidia GeForce RTX 3070 OC, drivers always up to date

Comment: What GPU? Drivers up-to-date?  Recommend editing that info into your question.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, try unregistering it with `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04`, then run `ubuntu2204.exe install --gui=none`. This will suppress the graphical installer ("Out of Box Experience", Canonical calls it) and use the "normal" WSL installer. If that installs properly, then `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install xterm && xterm`.  Does the diagonal appear on Xterm?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to finish the installation by locating the "OK" button that is invisible in the bottom right part of the screen. You'll see the pointer change when you come accross the button. That's how I do it.